# show dialog then call method in it's OnLoad method

Tags: winforms

I use C#, Winforms.
From MainForm, I instantiate MailSendForm dialog form which sends an email, the send method is in it's OnLoad method, there is progress bar on this form that shows the sending progress.

The problem is that the form doesn't show up, untill the send finishes and the message box that shows "Success", is closed.

Is there a way to show the sending form before the send begins?

```
    //--- MainForm

    private void SendOrder(...)
    {
        var sm = new MailSendForm(...);
        sm.ShowDialog();
}


    //--- MailSendForm

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        SendEmail();
    }

    private void SendEmail()
    {
   ....

        // Send mail.
        var success = mailman.SendEmail(email);
        if (success)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("email sent successfully");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(mailman.LastErrorText);
        }
}


    public void mailman_OnPercentDone(object source, Chilkat.PercentDoneEventArgs args)
    {
        progressBar.EditValue = args.PercentDone;

        if (_cancelled)
        {
            args.Abort = true;
        }
        Application.DoEvents();

    }
```

Comment: You can use the Form.Shown event. In addition, you will probably want to perform the sending on a separate thread, for example by wrapping that up into a `Task<T>`. If you do that, make sure to don't interact with the UI on your task thread. Instead use functions such as `BeginInvoke` whenever you want to update the progress bar.

Comment: The window doesn't become visible until *after* the Load event finished executing.  Which of course is going to take a while since you are sending an email message.  Using the Shown event is not a workaround either, you'll have a partially updated window that's still completely dead to the world.  Use a BackgroundWorker instead.  Or leverage the SmtpClient.SendMailAsync() method instead.

Comment: Actually I'm using a third party library for mail sending (Chilkat). I'll try the shown method.

Answer (score 0):

the Shown event solved my problem.

Thank you  Eiríkur Fannar Torfason.